# ShippingOrderProcessor not registered well?

Tags: 8, commerce

I'm trying to implement @jsacksick solution which should force displaying shipping costs on cart page (normally it doesn't exist at that step yet). I created a new module for this and it's structure is simple:

```
shipping_fix
  src
    ShippingOrderProcessor.php
  shipping_fix.info.yml
  shipping_fix.module
  shipping_fix.services.yml
```

ShippingOrderProcessor.php is exact copy of @jsacksick class:
https://gist.github.com/jsacksick/fde031197df92236ef5a916775e17a2e

info file contains:

```
name: Shipping fix
description: Fixes missing shipping info on cart page
type: module
core: 8.x
dependencies:
```

module file is empty and services file contains:

```
services:
  shipping_fix.shipping_order_processor:
    class: Drupal\shipping_fix\ShippingOrderProcessor
    tags:
      - { name: commerce_shipping.shipping_order_processor, priority: -300 }
```

But it's not working. I tried setting break points inside `__construct()` and `process()` methods of that class, but they are never reached.

Tried changing last row here to:

```
 - { name: commerce_order.order_processor, priority: -300 }
```

as explained here: https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/orders/order-refresh-and-process

but then my site crashes when I try to clear the cache?

So to me it looks like that I didn't register this processor object well. Most likely problem is in services file, but I can't figure out what it is ("**commerce_shipping.shipping_order_processor**" is correct value?).

Tried dumping services with drush like:

```
drush devel:services
drush devel-container-services
drush devel-services
```

and even devel mode is turned on for each try I get:
*Command "devel-container-services" is not defined.*
or similar.

I activated the my module of course, tried clearing caches, but didn't help.

**Update:**
The error which I get when I change last row of services file to:

```
 - { name: commerce_order.order_processor, priority: -300 }
```

is:

*Service 'shipping_fix.shipping_order_processor' for consumer 'commerce_order.order_refresh' does not implement Drupal\commerce_order\OrderProcessorInterface.*

And ShippingOrderProcess.php file starts with:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Drupal\my_module\OrderProcessor;

use Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderInterface;
use Drupal\commerce_order\OrderProcessorInterface;
use Drupal\commerce_shipping\ShipmentManagerInterface;
use Drupal\commerce_shipping\ShippingOrderManagerInterface;
use Drupal\profile\Entity\Profile;

/**
 * Ensures there are shipments from the start.
 */
final class ShippingProcessor implements OrderProcessorInterface {

  /**
   * The shipping order manager.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\commerce_shipping\ShippingOrderManagerInterface
   */
  protected $shippingOrderManager;

  /**
   * The shipment manager.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\commerce_shipping\ShipmentManagerInterface
   */
  protected $shipmentManager;


  public function __construct(ShippingOrderManagerInterface $shippingOrderManager, ShipmentManagerInterface $shipmentManager) {
    $this->shippingOrderManager = $shippingOrderManager;
    $this->shipmentManager = $shipmentManager;
  }

...
```

**Update 2:**

Managed to clear the cache:
For my file structure name space has to be:

```
namespace Drupal\shipping_fix;
```

Also changed servies file and now it looks like:

```
services:
  shipping_fix.shipping_order_processor:
    class: Drupal\shipping_fix\ShippingProcessor
    arguments: ['@commerce_shipping.order_manager', '@commerce_shipping.shipment_manager']
    tags:
      - { name: commerce_order.order_processor, priority: -300 }
```

Now cache clearing works, but I still don't see shipping costs on cart page...

Comment: `but then my site crashes when I try to clear the cache?` what error do you get?

Comment: "Service 'shipping_fix.shipping_order_processor' for consumer 'commerce_order.order_refresh' does not implement Drupal\commerce_order\OrderProcessorInterface." ?!?

Comment: In **ShippingOrderProcessor.php** you probably have `namespace Drupal\my_module\OrderProcessor;` and forgot to replace the `my_module` part with `shipping_fix`.

Comment: Yes, that was the case, but do I have also to pass somehow those parameters for the constructor?

Comment: Should I add something like:
arguments: ['@commerce_shipping.order_manager', '@commerce_shipping.shipment_manager']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

In this case, you'll want to run this before the `commerce_shipping.early_order_processor`, set priority to 300

```
services:
  shipping_fix.shipping_order_processor:
    class: Drupal\shipping_fix\ShippingProcessor
    arguments: ['@commerce_shipping.order_manager', '@commerce_shipping.shipment_manager']
    tags:
      - { name: commerce_order.order_processor, priority: 300 }
```

Comment: I'm afraid to say it (after all this trouble) but it seems to work! Thank you so much for helping me!